# How to empty the contents of continuosly streaming file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, centos

i have the program running using this command

`command 2> sample.txt`

now that file is growing continuously and command will exit in 5-6 days and i beleive that file size won't go in GB

I tried this

`echo "" > sample.txt` but thats not making any differnce to it and filesize is growing.

i was thinking of setting up cron job after 1 hour to empty its contents

How can i empty the contents of file

Comment: What does `cp /dev/null sample.txt` do for you?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46549/977 on Unix.SE, I wrote a perl program there that you can use in the future to keep only the last X bytes of output.

Answer (score 2):

Since the file is held open by the application, I don't think you can just empty it traditionally. Googling a bit I found this:

> Assuming that the author of the code writing the never-ending file knows even a little bit about unix:
>
> 1. For this process there is a configuration file, which names the output logfile.
> 2. The process "reconfigures" itself when it receives a SIGHUP signal,
>      by re-reading the config file, and if the name of the logfile changed, then close the old one, open the new one.
>
> This is pretty much UNIX standard for a never-ending log writer program.

Other than that, I can't find any obvious solution, since you used `>` and not `>>`. Next time you might want to redirect through `truncate` or something of the sort to avoid this problem of an infinitely-open logfile.

Comment: i could not understood , what should i do next time, i mean the complete command

Comment: The never ending file is being written by shell redirection, so unfortunately HUP isn't going to be useful. Truncate isn't going to be helpful, as you can't pipe (redirect) through it. But `>>` would help.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

> cat /dev/null > sample.txt

or

> `>`sample.txt

Comment: You meant `cat`, not `cp`. `cp` would complain `cp: missing destination file operand after \`/dev/null' 
Try \`cp --help' for more information.` Except of course OP said he already tried `echo "" > sample.txt`, which is basically the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The following command should work:

```
cat /dev/null > sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use logrotate, it is aimed exactly for this mission